# Why, for $f(n) = n \cdot \sqrt n$ and $g(n)=n(\log n)^5$, we have $f = \omega(g)$? log is base 2

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

Could you please explain me why that's the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$f(n) = \omega(g(n))$ if, for every constant $c$, there is some value $n_0$ (possibly depending on $c$) such that the following is satisfied by all $n \ge n_0$:
$$
f(n) \ge c g(n).
$$

Intuitively,  $f(n)$ grows faster than any scaled-up (by a multiplicative constant) version of $g(n)$.

This is the case with your particular choice of $f$ and $g$, as you can check by taking the limit of their ratio:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n \sqrt{n}}{n \log^5 n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\sqrt{n}}{\log^5 n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \left( \frac{n^\frac{1}{10}}{\log n} \right)^5 = +\infty,
$$
since, by L'Hôpital's rule:
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n^\frac{1}{10}}{\log n} =
\lim_{n \to \infty}  \frac{\frac{1}{10} n^{-\frac{9}{10}}}{\frac{1}{n \ln 2}} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{\ln 2}{10} n^{1/10} = +\infty.
$$

Comment: So, it means that Ω(g) or (()? See the confusing part is, that in the booksi has the following rule: limn→∞ f(n)/g(n) $= 0 ⇒ f = Ω(g) and limn→∞ f(n)/g(n) = ∞ ⇒ f = ω(g). So, which one applies here?

Comment: What's confusing? Both of them apply. Indeed both of the following statements are true $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ and $f(n) = \omega(g(n))$. In fact, $f(n)=\omega(g(n))$ implies that $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$. Informally, you can imagine $f(n) = \omega(g(n))$ as meaning "$f(n)$ grows **faster** than $g(n)$" and $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ as "$f(n)$ grows **at least as fast** as $g(n)$".

Comment: I mean that f(n) >= g(n)? why? How it can be ()=Ω(()) if our limit is +∞

Comment: If $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = +\infty$ then $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \neq 0$ and hence $f(n) = \Omega(g(n))$ (as per the rule you posted, assuming that `$=` means $\neq$).

Comment: I am so sorry. I confused the definitions. I meant these ones: limn→∞ f(n)/g(n) $= ∞ ⇒ f = O(g) limn→∞ f(n)/g(n) = 0 ⇒ f = o(g)

Comment: Neither of those two definitions applies to this case.

Comment: I know that. Just wanted to ask what to in this case?

Comment: I already answered. The only two that apply are $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} = +\infty$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(n)}{g(n)} \neq 0$ meaning that $f(n) = \omega(g(n))$ and, trivially, $f(n)=\Omega(g(n))$.